# How to showThumbs appedTo jFiler-input-dragDrop class (jquery.filer)

Tags: javascript

How to showThumbs appedTo jFiler-input-dragDrop class (jquery.filer)

```
extensions: ['jpg','png','jpeg'],
changeInput: '<div class="jFiler-input-dragDrop"><div class="jFiler-input-inner"><div class="jFiler-input-icon"><i class="icon-jfi-cloud-up-o"></i></div><div class="jFiler-input-text"><h3>Drag&Drop files here</h3> <span style="display:inline-block; margin: 15px 0">or</span></div><a class="jFiler-input-choose-btn blue">Browse Files</a></div></div>',
showThumbs: true,
appendTo: null,
```

Answer (score 0):

appendTo: '.jFiler-input-dragDrop'